# Getting link to file in Ubuntu folder

Tags: thunderbird

I have a file in the ubuntu Thunderbird Attachment folder, and it has been synced to the cloud. But in Thunderbird a link was never created in the email I wanted to send. How can I get a link I can send in email?

Answer (score 0):

**To send an attachment** in Thunderbird, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for a new message window, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to attach a file:

[image: TBird attachment plus link]

**To send a link to the file in Ubuntu One**, you have to publish it, then copy the link into the email.

Open Nautilus and find the file you previously uploaded, then right click it and select `Ubuntu One -> Publish`. Wait a moment for the file to publish, then right-click the same file and select `Ubuntu One -> Copy Web Link`

[image: Ubuntu One publish dialogue]

[image: Ubuntu One copy web link dialogue]

Now, compose your email and insert the link to the file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

One other way to get the link is to log in to Ubuntu One in the web browser and find the file. Click on 'More' to the right of it, and publish & copy the public link that way.

[image: Ubuntu One web interface]

[Source](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/is-there-a-way-to-let-someone-without-a-ubuntu-one-account-download-files/)

There are many cloud services you can use, the instructions are slightly different for each. If you are not using Ubuntu One then edit your question with the name of the cloud service (Dropbox, etc) for a more specific answer.